# ASP.NET - Refreshing GridView Data on Page After Button Click

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, soap

I've been working with C# and .NET for quite some time now, but am currently working on my first ever web application with ASP.NET. It took me quite some time playing around to realize that the Page_Load function was getting called before my button event handler, though, at this point I've got the application working properly around this behavior. However, the issue I'm having is this:

I have a GridView control that is bound to a SortedList in my application. The button click event handler saves data in a form to the database (actually, saves data via a SOAP service), then updates the list that the GridView is bound to in order to reflect the most up-to-date data (again, updates the list from the SOAP service). However, because the page refreshes before my button click event handler fires, the data doesn't actually appear updated on the page. What is the proper way to handle a situation like this? How can I get the data on the page to be refreshed, or at least up-to-date, after the button handler saves data even though the page has already refreshed? I've been struggling with this for quite awhile now, so any code example or links that'll help explain this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be of use: [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms178472.aspx').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try inside `Page_Load`

```
if (!IsPostBack)
 {
  //Bind your Grid
 }
```

Comment: I actually already have this and thus the GridView looks fine the first time I grab the list of items from the web service and load the page. It's just after trying to add to the list with the button click that it gets out of sync (note - I've noticed if I manually refresh the page after the button click handler finishes, my GridView is as expected...but I shouldn't have to do that manual refresh!)

Comment: in  button click event  rebind your `grid` for new updated record.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize I needed to rebind the data everytime! I assumed that once bound, as my list changed, so would the control.  So I've fixed it by just resetting the DataSource and then Binding it again in the click button handler. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just write your code in below if condition.

```
 if(!IsPostBack)
      {
         write your code here in formload.
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to correct Harag's link to the resource regarding the **page lifecycle**. It can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx.
Though not an answer to the OP's question, I restate it because it's such an important concept to know once you start programming web forms on a more serious basis.